# Better TypeInitializationException (innerException is also null)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, nlog

**Intro**

When an user creates a mistake in the configuration of NLog (like invalid XML), We (NLog) throw a `NLogConfigurationException`. The exception contains the description what is wrong.

But sometimes this `NLogConfigurationException` is "eaten" by a `System.TypeInitializationException` if the first call to NLog is from a static field/property.

**Example**

E.g. if the user has this program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NLog;

namespace TypeInitializationExceptionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        //this throws a NLogConfigurationException because of bad config. (like invalid XML)
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and there is a mistake in the config, NLog throws:

```
throw new NLogConfigurationException("Exception occurred when loading configuration from " + fileName, exception);
```

But the user will see:

[image: Throw exception]

"Copy exception details to the clipboard":

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: The type initializer for 'TypeInitializationExceptionTest.Program' threw an exception.

So the message is gone!

**Questions**

1. Why is innerException not visible? (tested in Visual Studio 2013).
2. Can I send more info to the `TypeInitializationException`? Like a message? We already sending an innerException.
3. Can we use another exception or are there properties on `Exception` so that more info is reported?
4. Is there another way to give (more) feedback to the user?

**Notes**

- of course we have no influence on the program written by the user.
- I'm one of the maintainers of NLog.
- Do you like to test it by yourself? Checkout https://github.com/NLog/NLog/tree/TypeInitializationException-tester and start NLog/src/NLog.netfx45.sln

**Edit**:

please note that I'm the library maintainer, not the user of the library. **I cannot change the calling code!**

Comment: That's pretty much the behavior of the CLR and you can't do much about it. Most people should be aware they need to take a look at the `InnerException`, and `ToString()` will also print the inner exception's message and stack trace. The only thing you could do is return a no-op logger so the user's app doesn't crash, but you'll get the obvious implications of that.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski but why is even the `InnerException` `null`? Also "Copy exception details to the clipboard" won't reveal the cause! (tested in DEBUG)

Comment: Sorry, I can't repro this. I get a non-null `InnerException` of type `NLogConfigurationException` with message: `Error when setting property 'Layout' on NLog.Targets.DatabaseParameterInfo`, which itself has an `InnerException` of type `ArgumentException` with message `LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'thisIsWrong'`

Comment: @Julian This was really a good question. I'm going to write a blog post on the same with more insights.

Comment: Thanks @vendettamit! Looking forward to it!

Comment: Here's the post.. Though not much different from the answer http://www.cshandler.com/2016/02/why-typeinitializationexception-has.html

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample which exhibits this behavior. In my attempts to reproduce it, the inner exception was correctly set

Comment: The example is really minimal (with maybe a lot of code around it). It's in the linked github link

Comment: I tested this in VS2013, and yes, the exception did show in my locals window, and I could see the InnerException, like @LucasTrzesniewski says in his answer. However, in my VS2015, the exception did not show up in my locals window, so I couldn't see the InnerException. Are you sure about the VS version you tested it in? It looks like a bug in VS2015.

Comment: @Stephen I tested this on VS2015

Comment: That's strange, because I can't see the exception in my locals (in the github project from @Julian)

Comment: However, like @HansPassant said, if you turn on 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode', the 'View Detail...' link is visibile in the Exception popup, and there you can see the inner exception. So the inner exception is just not reported properly. Still looks like a bug to me.

Comment: "Press Any Key" when actually the only key that will do anything when pressed is <RETURN>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll just point out the underlying problem you are dealing with here.  You are fighting a bug in the debugger, it has a very simple workaround.  Use Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.  Also untick Just My Code for the most informative debugging report:

[image]

If Just My Code is ticked then the exception report is less informative but still can be drilled down easily by clicking the "View Detail" link.

The option name is unnecessarily cryptic.  What it *really* does is tell Visual Studio to use an older version of the debugging engine. Anybody that uses VS2013 or VS2015 will have this trouble with the new engine, possibly VS2012.  Also the basic reason that this issue did not have be addressed in NLog before.

While this is a very good workaround, it is not exactly easy to discover.  Nor would programmers particularly like to use the old engine, shiny new features like return value debugging and E+C for 64-bit code are not supported by the old engine.  Whether this is a truly a bug, an oversight or a technical limitation in the new engine is hard to guess.  This is excessively ugly so don't hesitate to label it "bug", I strongly recommend you take this to connect.microsoft.com.  Everybody will be ahead when it gets fixed, I scratched my head over this at least once that I remember.  Drilled it down by using Debug > Windows > Exceptions > ticked CLR Exceptions at the time.

A workaround for this very unfortunate behavior is sure to be ugly.  You do have to delay raising the exception until program execution has progressed far enough.  I don't know your codebase well enough, but delaying parsing the config until the first logging command ought to take care of it.  Or store the exception object and throw it on the first log command, probably easier.

Comment: Can confirm this will print the innerException when "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"  is on (VS2015 update 1). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The reason I see is because the Type initialization of Entry point class is failed. Since no type was initialized, so the Type loader has nothing to report about the failed type in `TypeInitializationException`.

But if you change the Static initializer of logger to other class and then refer that class in Entry method. you'll get the InnerException on TypeInitialization exception.

```
static class TestClass
{
    public static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();  
}

class Program
{            
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = TestClass.logger;
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now you'll get the InnerException because the Entry type was loaded to report the TypeInitializationException.

[image]

Hope now you get the idea to keep the Entry point clean and Bootstrap the application from Main() instead of static property of Entry point class.

**Update 1**

You can also utilize the `Lazy<>` to avoid the execution of configuration initialization at declaration.

```
class Program
{
    private static Lazy<Logger> logger = new Lazy<Logger>(() => LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger());

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this will throw TypeInitialization with InnerException as a NLogConfigurationException because of bad config. (like invalid XML)
        logger.Value.Info("Test");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, try `Lazy<>` in the LogManager for logger instantiation so that the configuration initialization happens when actually the first log statement occurs.

**Update 2**

I analyzed the source code of NLog and seems like it's already implemented and It make sense. According to the comments on property "NLog should not throw exception unless specified by property `LogManager.ThrowExceptions` in LogManager.cs".

Fix - In the LogFactory class the private method GetLogger() has the initialization statement which is causing the exception to happen. If you introduce a try catch with the check of property `ThrowExceptions` then you can prevent the initialization exception.

```
      if (cacheKey.ConcreteType != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    newLogger.Initialize(cacheKey.Name, this.GetConfigurationForLogger(cacheKey.Name, this.Configuration), this);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if(ThrowExceptions && ex.MustBeRethrown())
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Also it would be great to have these exceptions/errors stored somewhere so that It can be traced why Logger initialization failed because the they were ignored due to `ThrowException`.

Comment: This is a nice approach, but I can't change the calling code.

Comment: @Julian I have updated the answer with a fix in NLog library.

Comment: thanks for the proposed change in NLog, but we are aware of this. We cannot change this for now as it will be a breaking change. The exception is intended, although the docs could use an improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is the static initialization happens when the class is first referenced. In your `Program` it happens even before the `Main()` method. So as rule of thumb - avoid any code that can fail in static initialization method. As for your particular problem - use lazy approach instead:

```
private static Lazy<Logger> logger = 
  new Lazy<Logger>(() => LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger());

static void Main() {
  logger.Value.Log(...);
}
```

So the initialization of logger will happen (and possibly fail) when you'll first access the logger - not in some crazy static context.

**UPDATE**

It is ultimately burden of user of your library to stick to the best practices. So if it were me I'd keep it as it is. There are few options though if you really have to solve it on your end:

1) Don't throw exception - ever - this is valid approach in logging engine, and  how `log4net` works - i.e.

```
static Logger GetCurrentClassLogger() {
    try {
       var logger = ...; // current implementation
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // let the poor guy now something is wrong - provided he is debugging
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
        // null logger - every single method will do nothing 
        return new NullLogger();
    }
}
```

2) wrap the lazy approach around the implementation of `Logger` class (I know your `Logger` class is much more complex, for sake of this problem let's assume it has just one method `Log` and it takes `string className` to construct `Logger` instance.

```
class LoggerProxy : Logger {
  private Lazy<Logger> m_Logger;
  // add all arguments you need to construct the logger instance
  public LoggerProxy(string className) {
    m_Logger = new Lazy<Logger>(() => return new Logger(className)); 
  }
  public void Log(string message) {
   m_Logger.Value.Log(message);
  }
}

static Logger GetCurrentClassLogger() {
  var className = GetClassName();
  return new LoggerProxy(className);
}
```

You'll get rid of this problem (the real initialization will happen while first log method is called and it is backward-compatible approach); only problem is you've added another layer (I don't expect any drastic downgrade of performance, but some logging engines are really into micro-optimization).

Comment: wow!! Didn't saw your answer. I just updated mine including this approach as well. Hope you won't mind. :)

Comment: This is a nice approach, but I can't change the calling code

Comment: @Julian - and that is a problem ? You just need to wrap it to be backward-compatible  :)

Comment: This is a nice approach, but probably you'll might want to make it thread-safe, see e.g. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @odrej I don't write the calling code. Please check the TS

Comment: @Julian - I understand, see my update - lazy approach is still possible, not sure you have to do it though :)

Answer (score 3):

I said in an earlier comment that I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Then it occurred to me you were *only* looking for it in the popup exception dialog, which doesn't display a *show details* link.

So here's how you can get at the `InnerException` anyway, because **it definitely is there**, except Visual Studio doesn't report it for some reason (probably because it's in the entry point type as vendettamit figured out).

So, when you run the tester branch, you get the following dialog:

[image: Exception dialog]

And it doesn't show the *View Details* link.

The *Copy exception detail to the clipboard* isn't particularly helpful either:

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: The type initializer for 'TypeInitializationExceptionTest.Program' threw an exception.

Now, dismiss the dialog with the *OK* button and head towards the *Locals* debug window. Here's what you'll see:

[image: Locals view]

See? The `InnerException` definitely *is* there, and you found a VS quirk :-)

Comment: No it isn't there, but that's explained in another post. There is no innerException but `main` has not been called yet.

Comment: @Julian I wrote this post because I disagree with that other one - it *is* there, as evidenced by this answer, but VS doesn't show it due to a quirk. I reproduced this with your GitHub solution. Did you try to follow the steps in my answer exactly as described?

Comment: I will retest it. Would be great if this was true.

Comment: tested it in VS2013 (update 5) and locals is empty. So won't work :(

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I see now is:

move the static initializes (fields) to a static constructor with a `try catch`

Answer (score 1):

[System.TypeInitializationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx) is always or almost always occurred from not correct initialisation the static members of a class.

You have to check `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` via debugger. I'm sure the error is occurred inside that part of code.

```
//go into LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger() method
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Also i suggest you double check your app.config and make sure you haven't included anything wrong.

`System.TypeInitializationException` is thrown whenever a static constructor throws an exception, or whenever you attempt to access a class where the static constructor threw an exception.

When `.NET` loads the type, it must prepare all it's static fields before ***the first time*** that you use the type. Sometimes, initialization requires running code. It is when that code fails that you get a `System.TypeInitializationException`.

According the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx)

> When a class initializer fails to initialize a type, a TypeInitializationException is created and passed a reference to the exception thrown by the type's class initializer. The InnerException property of TypeInitializationException holds the underlying exception.
>   TypeInitializationException uses the HRESULT COR_E_TYPEINITIALIZATION, that has the value 0x80131534.
>   For a list of initial property values for an instance of TypeInitializationException, see the TypeInitializationException constructors.

1) The `InnerException` is not visible it is very typical for this type of Exception. The version of Visual Studio doesn't matter (ensure that the *"Enable the exception assistant"* option is checked - `Tools> Options>Debugging>General`)

2) Usually the `TypeInitializationException` hides the real exception which can be viewed via InnerException. But the test example below shows how you can populate inner exception info:

```
public class Test {
    static Test() {
        throw new Exception("InnerExc of TypeInitializationExc");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
    }
}
```

> But sometimes this NLogConfigurationException is "eaten" by an
>   System.TypeInitializationException if the first call to NLog is from a
>   static field/property.

Nothing strange. Someone missed the `try catch` block somewhere.

Comment: You're just explaining what a `TypeInitializationException` is... OP seems to be well aware of that.

Comment: Yes thanks, but I'm also aware of this. I will check "Enable the exception assistant", thanks for that hint.

Comment: "Nothing strange. Someone missed the try catch block somewhere" not true as we do advise to make a static field. This can't be fixed with a `try catch`