# TypeInitializationException in NLog LoggerFactory

Tags: c#, exception, nlog, typeinitializeexception

I develop a WPF application that uses NLog. It has been deployed to a few prospective customers, and in *one of them*, the application worked fine for a week and now it doesn't even open. That is, you double click the app icon, and nothing happens, literally. Not even the logging inside a `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` catch clause.

I was able to identify an event in the Windows Event Viewer (see message below).

What bogs me down is the sudden appearence of this error after a week of flawless operation, and my inability to interpret this message or finding info about it online.

```
Aplicativo: ForceViewer.exe
Versão do Framework: v4.0.30319
Descrição: O processo foi terminado devido a uma exceção sem tratamento.
Informações da Exceção: System.Xml.XmlException
em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.Exception)
em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
em System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
em System.Configuration.XmlUtil..ctor(System.IO.Stream, System.String, Boolean, System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
em System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()

Informações da Exceção: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
em System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean)
em System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
em System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
em System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(System.Object, System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs)

Informações da Exceção: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
em System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
em System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
em NLog.Common.InternalLogger.GetSettingString(System.String, System.String)
em NLog.Common.InternalLogger.GetSetting[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.String, System.String, Boolean)
em NLog.Common.InternalLogger.Reset()
em NLog.Common.InternalLogger..cctor()

Informações da Exceção: System.TypeInitializationException
em NLog.Common.InternalLogger.Log(System.Exception, NLog.LogLevel, System.String)
em NLog.Internal.ExceptionHelper.MustBeRethrown(System.Exception)
em NLog.LogFactory.get_Configuration()
em NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(LoggerCacheKey)
em NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(System.String)
em NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(System.String)
em Miotec.ForceViewer.App..cctor()

Informações da Exceção: System.TypeInitializationException
em Miotec.ForceViewer.App.Main(System.String[])
```

Here is my App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static string AppName = "ForceViewer 1.1";

    static readonly Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, AppName);

    // APPARENTLY the exception happens in the line below:
    static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(App).FullName);


    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen("Splash.png");
        splashScreen.Show(true);

        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            var app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        else
        {
            Extensions.EnviaMensagemPraAtivarOutraJanela();
        }
    }


    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        WpfLauncher.Launch(this, new ForceViewerBootstrapper(AppName));
        logger.Info($"Aplicação {AppName} iniciada");
    }
}
```

UPDATE (with additional, possibly relevant info):

Some people mentioned NLog XML config file, but I am using a runtime configuration, as follows:

```
        var dirname = Path.Combine(@"C:\\AppFolder", appName, "logs");

        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirname);

        var filename = Path.Combine(dirname, $"{appName}.log");

        var filetarget = new FileTarget("app")
        {
            FileName = filename,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            Layout = "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} (${logger:shortName=true})",
            AutoFlush = true,
            MaxArchiveFiles = 8,
            ArchiveAboveSize = 1048576,
            ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Friday,
            ConcurrentWrites = true
        };

        var asyncTarget = new AsyncTargetWrapper("app", filetarget);

        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        config.AddRuleForAllLevels(asyncTarget);
        config.AddTarget(asyncTarget);
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Additionally, the "stack trace" (which in the case of a Windows Event seems to be printed sort of backwards) suggests NLog itself is getting an exception from the `System.Configuration` classes, as seen from decompilation of `InternalLogger`:

```
  namespace NLog.Common
  {
      //...
      public static class InternalLogger
      {
          //...
          private static string GetSettingString(string configName, string envName)
          {
              // Line below seems to be throwing an exception
              string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configName];
              //..
```

Comment: What logger are you using (nlog config)? could it be some permission issue which causes this? what is causing the `System.Xml.XmlException`?

Comment: At a guess, one of the Xml config files (e.g. `App.exe.config`) has been corrupted?

Comment: @StuartLC I agree that this seems to be the problem. But what then? I wonder what could have caused the problem, in one hand, and in the other hand, I don't how how this should be corrected/prevented. Also I'm not sure how I should debug this, since the problem only manifests itself in the machine of a client to which we only have remote access.

Comment: Cause could be user fiddling, virus, disk failing, etc One if the risks of fat/smart client 

Answer (score 3):

Probably there is a config mistake in your NLog (XML) config.

So why do you get a `TypeInitializationException` and not a helpful message? That's because your initializing NLog before starting your program. The line:

```
static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(App).FullName);
```

will be run before the `Main` because it's a static field. Unfortunately NLog cannot throw a better exception (see: [Better TypeInitializationException (innerException is also null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994470/better-typeinitializationexception-innerexception-is-also-null))

Recommendation: in this case is recommend to have a non-static Logger, or, a `static Lazy<Logger>`:

```
static readonly Lazy<Logger> logger = new Lazy<Logger>(() => LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(App).FullName));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By static lazy logger, you mean something like this? `private static readonly Lazy<Logger> logger = new Lazy<Logger>(() => LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(App).FullName));`

Comment: I have realized that I am not using a XML config for NLog, I perform the configuration in the code itself (I know it is not ideal, but that's the way it is now). Also, it seems that the original exception might be caused by .Net classes, specifically `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`, which throw a `ConfigurationErrorsException`. (See my update)

Comment: So your question is solved isn't? You know the root cause?

Comment: Well, actually not, but I suppose it's not quite an NLog fault. I guess I'll have to investigate further why the `ConfigurationErrorsException is happening in the first place. Anyway, thanks for your response!