# NLog GetCurrentClassLogger() throws TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm porting code that has worked for a few years now from a machine running Windows 7 to Windows 10.  The project is a Class Library that uses .NET Framework 4.5.2 with NLog 4.4.12.  After recompiling, the application throws a TypeInitializationException in the constructor.

Tried the following:

1. Comment out NLog code - **success**.
2. Upgraded NLog to 4.6.2 - **fail**.
3. Created a Test Console Application to verify NLog was installed properly - **success**.
4. Tried stripping down NLog.config to just console target/rule - **fail**.
5. Rebuilt class step-by-step - **fails** immediately when introduction NLog intializer.

Throws exception on (won't even enter constructor): `private static NLog.Logger m_nLog = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();`

NLog.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd" 
    autoReload="true" 
    throwExceptions="true" 
    internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

<targets>
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" 
        layout     = "${time} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />

    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" 
        fileName   = "${basedir}/Logs/${shortdate}.log" 
        layout     = "${time} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info"  writeTo="console" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
</rules>
```

- same NLog.Config used with Test Console Application, which works.

No idea how to proceed or determine the inner exception.

Comment: to get a more meaningfull error, try making your `m_nLog` variable _non-static_ so that it gets initialized later, thus being able to provide you with a better error message than an TypeInitializationException.

Comment: Also make sure to remove `throwExceptions="true"` it is only meant for NLog Unit Testing. Try also to enable the NLog InternalLogger by configuring `internalLogLevel="Trace"` and look in the log file `c:\temp\nlog-internal.log`. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think to remove static for better testing.  I'm sure I just followed the NLog tutorial when I first added logging a few years ago. Worked out of the box and never looked back till now!  Turns out, NLog couldn't find the configuration file. Even though, I set NLog.config file with "Build Action = Content" and "Copy to Output Directory = Copy always", my class starts and external program and used a working directory that is different. In the end, a week wasted, but user error!  Thanks for the advise Pedro!

Comment: Rolf, I appreciate you help as well - I had already tried everything in the NLog Troubleshooting link (should have mentioned in my original post).

Answer (score 2):

If there is an issue in NLog, e.g. a wrong logging configuration, NLog could throw an exception.

If this exception is throw before the startup type is contructed, .NET will hide the exception with a `TypeInitializationException` (See also [Better TypeInitializationException (innerException is also null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994470/better-typeinitializationexception-innerexception-is-also-null)).

E.g. in this case:

```cs
class Program
{
    // this throws a NLogConfigurationException because of bad config. (like invalid XML)
    // as this issue will be throw before Main() is called, you will get
    // a TypeInitializationException instead of a NLogConfigurationException
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

### Solutions

3 possible solutions:

#### Using lazy

```
class Program
{
    private static Lazy<Logger> logger = new Lazy<Logger>(() => LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger());

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

#### Create the logger in the main()

```cs
class Program
{
    private static Logger logger;

    static void Main()
    {
        logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

#### Create a local logger

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        private logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally figured it out this morning with Pedro's suggestion above.  Turns out, even though I verified the NLog configuration file existed, my class app is launched with an external application that has a different working directory (complete user error). Once I copied over the config, all worked perfectly!  I had tried all 3 suggestions you posted above, which I found in previous posts (should have mentioned in original post).  Sorry for wasting anyone's time!